# Default binary log position for change_master_to in MySQL circular replication?

Tags: mysql, replication

I have two MySQL servers set up with replication - lets say A and B for ease.

Currently B is a slave of A

To allow me to switch over to A in event of failure, I want to make this replication circular, so A is also a slave of B.

I know how to set this up using "change master to", but having read the documentation I am not clear on how to make sure that A starts replicating from B at the very end of B's binlog so it doesn't start to try and apply a bunch of SQL queries to the master that I don't want it to?

Am I making any sense?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? And are using GTID's or binlog file and position for your replication? (from your question I assume the latter, but it's best to check).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(-sorry if I have misunderstood)

(-assuming you are using binlog file and pos).

The key things to make sure of are that your servers have unique `server-ids` (if you have replication running already then this should be ok).

You also probably want to set:

```
auto_increment_increment
auto_increment_offset
```

values so that the two Databases don't generate overlapping primary keys.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-master.html

After that on your Slave DB (**B**), simply run `SHOW MASTER STATUS`.

Use those details to issue the `CHANGE MASTER` statement on DB **A**.

What you should find is that anything executed on **A** is then replicated to **B** and vice versa.

However anything executed on **A** shouldn't be replicated back from **B** to **A**.

And as such, the only queries written back to **A** will be those that are executed directly on **B**.

Finally, you will want to set **B** to read_only to prevent anyone accidentally writing to it, until such time as you want them to.